# Ubuntu Lucid (10.04) subpixel font rendering crashes Xorg

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, crash, xorg, rendering

I really don't know how to solve this on my own so I thought giving this site a chance. After upgrading to Lucid I ran into some problems. With some experimenting I came to a conclusion that if I enable subpixel smoothing on fonts the moment I start any other application not native to GTK+ (wine, openoffice, wxWidgets, ...) my X server crashes the same moment.

At first this seemed like something went wrong during installation. To cut the long story short, after 3 clean installations and whole bunch of experimenting the same thing happens all over again. Strange thing is... if I configure any other font smoothing besides subpixel, everything works like it should.

Any thoughs?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please say which graphical card and driver are you using? Have you tried an alternative one or another version?

Comment: I am using proprietary divers for built-in nVidia 6150. It's the latest drivers suggested by Ubuntu. I have tried other proprietary driver version and the same thing happened. I though it was because I used other version than latest.

Comment: Could you please follow the guide at http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/ServerDebugging so we can have more information?